# Mapstruct - no qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I try to autowire my mapstruct mapper:

```
@Mapper(uses = {
                A.class,
                B.class,
                C.class
        })
public interface WindowDtoMapper {

    WindowDtoMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(WindowDtoMapper.class);
    DetailedDto mapToDetailedDto(Window window);
    ReadDto mapToReadDto(Window window);
}
```

This works:

```
return WindowDtoMapper.INSTANCE.mapToDetailedDto(window)
```

But WHY I can't use:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AAA(){
private final WindowDtoMapper windowDtoMapper;


windowDtoMapper.mapToDetailedDto(window)
}
```

I get the following error:

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'pl.comp.window.application.mapper.WindowDtoMapper' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations: {}    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1717)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)

Maybe I should stay with the first working solution? Is it bad solution or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, MapStruct generates ordinary Java classes, and that's all. Spring has no way of knowing that you want these to be beans.

As described in [the MapStruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#using-dependency-injection), you can use `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")` to have MapStruct put `@Component` on the classes it creates (you'll need to make sure that the package with the mappers is getting component-scanned).

Comment: You can't use `Mappers#getMapper` with the spring component model. It only makes sense to use it with the default one

Comment: it works, thanks! I thought that mapstruct mappers are beans by default

Comment: @Filip I was under the impression you still _can_, but it's best to inject. Does MapStruct suppress the `getMapper` registration entirely with a different `componentModel`?

Comment: It doesn't surpress anything. The `getMapper` does nothing more then invoking the default constructor. So yes you can use it, but it doesn't work correctly when using it with other component models.

Comment: I am getting this exact same exception, but in a Junit test. The mapper interface is already set to use `componentModel = "spring"` and the test case file itself is annotated with `@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = {MetadataServiceImpl.class})`. Is there anything else that I need to add to make the mapper available in the ApplicationContext when running this test case?